# How to show/maintain Extend Session timeout Window in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have used rails devise gem for authentication. Specifically, I have used devise timeoutable module for session timeout with 30 minutes.

I need to make a pop up which prompts after 29 minutes & able to extend the session for next 30 minutes exactly same as that of implemented in Unfuddle.com .

On this prompt there are 2 buttons and one timer: "Stay logged in", "Logout", and timer for 60 seconds. If I click on "Stay logged in" button within 60 seconds then session should be extended up to next 30 minutes without change or refresh the page. If I click on Logout then user should be logout his session and redirects to login page. If I don't press any of the above 2 buttons within 60 seconds then it automatically redirects to the login page.
Guidance will be appreciated.

I have used following code in devise session_controller:

```
def skip_timeout

    request.env["devise.skip_trackable"] = true

end 

def extend_admin_session

    request.env["devise.skip_trackable"] = false

    @time_left_insec = Devise.timeout_in - (Time.now - admin_session["last_request_at"]).round

    render :json => @time_left_insec

end
```

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically set the timeout for each user, you can define a method in the user model called timeout_in that returns the timeout value.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise (...), :timeoutable

  def timeout_in
    if self.admin? 
      1.year
    else
      2.days
    end
  end
end
```

Thing is you need to define a method and have to call accordingly ...

I would suggests you to check out source code of [timeout module in Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb)

Hope this help you !!!

Comment: Thanks for your response Vinay. I have set up default time to 30 minutes in devise.rb file for all users, So that after 30 minutes, user's session gets destroyed. I  just wanted to extend the session between the interval of 29th to 30th minutes. So, I have done following steps but not find the solution : I requested the server between this interval (last 1 minute) for extending the session. But the java script timer and Rails timer is not matching this interval because when I click on "extend session" button rails already logged out the session & i am getting authenticity token error.Got Stuck